# Distance in arc length along the circle

Tags: geometry, curves, arc-length

In my notebook appears $d$ = distance in arc length along the circle. What does it mean??

Comment: Without any other context, we don't know. This perhaps just refers to the usual arc length, where $d = r\theta$, with $\theta$ in radians.

Comment: We need more information to answer your question i'm afraid.

Comment: For example, you want to find the distance from the North Pole to the South Pole, knowing the radius of the Earth $R$. If you can go through the center of the Earth, the distance would be $2R$. But if you go along the surface (on a circle containing the two poles), the distance is $\pi R$.

Comment: @Andrei thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you start at $(1,0)$ and move counterclockwise around the unit circle to point $(0,1)$ you will have traveled a quarter of the circle. All the way around would be $2\pi$ so in this case the "distance in arc length along the circle" is $\pi/2$. You make the same kind of calculation for the distance between any other pair of points on the circle.